# How can I use my camera as both VR and normal camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I am making a game that I need both vr and main camera. But when I build it it just stays as a vr camera. I want to make my camera to vr camera in another scene. What can I do

Answer (score 0):

Create a prefab for your camera (player) and call [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) for scene changes. Activate/deactive via script the camera (child object) you dont need.